# Access parent checkstyle.xml from child Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with parent, which contains checkstyle.xml for our organization. Is there a way to access this parent's checkstyle.xml from child projects? I've seen answers like accessing parent properties via `${project.parent.property-name}`, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Could you please show the structure of the project - the location of the pom.xml and checkstyle.xml files? Please show the excerpts from the POMs - property declaration and parent reference.